# content hide after data reload with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to learn ajax and i got small problem

I created a div

Here is my index.php

```
$con = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $database);
$selectchampions = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `experts`");
$row = $selectchampions->fetch_assoc();
<div id="summary"><h1><?php echo $row['expert_country']; ?></h1></div>
```

and this is the script

```
<script>
    function updateShouts() {
        // Assuming we have #shoutbox
        $('#summary').load('changediv.php');
    }
    setInterval("updateShouts()", 10000);
</script>
```

and changediv.php

```
$selectchampions = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `experts`");
$row = $selectchampions->fetch_assoc();
```

the problem is that after 1 second the content gets changed very well but it wouldn't render in html, if i check in the source of page it show the correct content but in the rendered page it will hide

example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning any HTML/content back to the call so it won't be showing anything...

In your `changediv.php` file, you need to fetch content and return it:

```
$selectchampions = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `experts`");
$row = $selectchampions->fetch_assoc();

echo $row['expert_country'];
```

<sup>*Just one thing to note though; it's always going to show the first row so you'll need to adjust that.*</sup>